# Is it possible to add scripts inside Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to reset my Realtime database values every 24 hours in Firebase. How can I create a backend with Firebase?

Comment: Well yes, but the answers were not very clear/understanding.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question, as it stands now, is not suitable for Stack Overflow, as it appears to be seeking recommendations for products, or could be seen as needing focus.  On Stack Overflow, it's expected that you do research and come prepared with code that isn't working the way you expect.  We can't really explain to you in short form you how to solve a very general problem like "create a backend".

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get started running periodic scripts that act on Firebase is through Google Cloud Functions, which Firebase integrates with. I recommend checking out the [introduction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), [sample use-cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases), and how to [run Cloud Functions on a schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).